# Does this Euler product have a name?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let

$$\displaystyle f(s) = \prod_p \left(1 - \frac{1}{2p^s}\right), \Re(s) > 1.$$

This Euler product converges. Does it have a name?

Comment: Did you mean to write your terms as $\left( 1-\frac{1}{2p^s}\right)^{-1}$ instead?

Comment: $$ f(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2^{-\omega(n)}\mu(n)}{n^s} $$

Answer (score 0):

It has an expression in terms of fractions involving $\zeta(s)$.
Start with 
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_p\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right), 
$$
and then
$$
f(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{2^{\omega (n)}n^s}.
$$
For the plus sign we have
$$
\prod_p \left(1+\frac{1}{2p^s}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)^2}{\zeta(2s)}.
$$
Reference: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product).

Answer (score 0):

It could help to visualize this product by rewriting it as $$f(s)=\prod_{p} (1-q^{-s})$$ where $$q=2p$$
Recall that $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\prod_{p} (1-p^{-s})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$$

So if you expand the product into a sum you should get an answer very similar to that, which is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(n)2^{-\omega(n)}}{n^s}$$
Where $\omega(n)$=amount of prime factors of n.

This looks to be similar to the identity $$\frac{\zeta^2(s)}{\zeta(2s)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}$$
but I could not find any way to relate your function to the above sum.